# Trouble with MS Word templates and 'sections'

Tags: page-layout, layout, template-design, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm trying to create a letterhead template that works like so:

- Front page containing one header image
- Continuation page containing alternate header image
- All additional pages automatically use continuation / alternate
  header

Here are the steps that I've taken so far:

1. Created the first page and added the header image
2. Clicked `Layouts > Breaks > Next Page`
3. Unchecked `Link to Previous`
4. Added alternate header image

So now I have a 2-page Word doc, with different headers on each. I can see in the status bar at the bottom that page 1 has 'section 1' and page 2 has 'section 2'.

However when I move my cursor to page 1, and type a load of text until it's full, the spillover doesn't go into page 2 as I'd hoped.

Instead it creates a new page, using the same header as page 1.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I set it so that the spillover goes into the second page that has already been created?

I've tried it without unchecking `Link to Previous` but then my alternate header overwrites the one on the first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior of a break in Word. Breaks are treated like character, and move with the text. You actually see the location of the break by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>.

What you are trying to do—having a different header for first page—is actually built into the header footer settings.

1. Double click in the header to edit it.
2. In the ribbon, in **Header & Footer Tools**, select **Different First Page**.

While the second page won't be visible in an empty document, the header/footer will be retained. So when you are creating your template, you can manually insert a page (not section) break with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, make your changes to the second page, and then delete the page break.

Comment: ah I could have sworn I tried that and had the same problem! nevertheless, I've just given it a try now and it worked like a treat... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is very usefull..
http://tutorialway.com/page-layout-in-microsoft-word/

Comment: Hi mackmans, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!